# How to pass arguments to kotlin script?

Tags: batch-file, kotlin

I have a windows batch

```
@echo off

setlocal
  call kotlinc-jvm -cp "%~dp0\lib\commons-cli-1.3.1.jar" -script "%~dp0\RmMvnRepo.kts" %*
endlocal
```

If I pass "-h" option to the batch, kotlinc-jvm own's help will display. But I want my `RmMvnRepo.kts` to receive the option. How to do that?

---

EDIT: No need to answer this question anymore. I've found a bug in kotlinc related to this.

Comment: Can you provide the YouTrack issue tracking the bug?

Comment: @mfulton26 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9370

Comment: You might post that link as an answer to your own question. That way you can accept it and this question will no longer show up as "unanswered", etc. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mfulton suggested, [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9370) describes the problem, so I will close this question.

From a comment on that ticket:

> This will be possible in 1.1.3 using the "--" delimiter for the compiler arguments and the rest (free arguments):

And the comment's example usage of `--`:

> ```
> kotlinc -script foo.kts -- -arg value
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Think of your code wrapped in main function. Then you can access arguments through `args` array.

```sh
Call the script with arguments
kotlinc -script ...kts "option1" "option2"
```

```kotlin
Access the arguments through args variable
println(args.size) // will output 2
```

Update: Try quotes to pass -h parameter

```sh
kotlinc -script ...kts "%*"
```

Comment: There are some typos here. And the length of an array is called `size`.

Comment: Via https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/do-scripts-accept-arguments-parameters-is-there-a-way-to-pass-objects-to-them/998 and https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/testData/codegen/script/parameter.kts this the correct answer to the question "How to accept kotlin script arguments" )